# Tips and Tricks to avoid iphone app crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

Is there any  tips to avoid crashing of iPhone applications. Sometime it is very difficult to understand where the problem is. 
What are the  possible reasons of iPhone app crashes ?

Comment: This are  nice posts about Debugging

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html
http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/

Comment: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

Comment: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Comment: another one. problem might be of os sdk os versions like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424210/iphone-development-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated/1486047#1486047   . Here changing the target from 3.0 to 3.1 did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the biggest causes of crashes on the iPhone platform is not following the [Cocoa Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) rules.

See this question: [Memory Management in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106627/memory-management-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3):

Crashes are caused by bugs in your code. To prevent these you need to:

```
(a) learn how to write robust code
(b) learn how to test your code (with particular attention to stress testing)
(c) learn how to debug
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to the iPhone-platform, but what helps a lot is catching (proper) exceptions and logging the exceptions-messages somewhere so you know *what* went wrong and don't only get a "force close"-message with little or nor further information.

Answer (score 1):

you should add NSZombie class to your project to avoid EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors... even this helps to understand what's happened. So to do it you should click on the Get Info of your Executables and then go to the Arguments and there you can add NSZombieEnabled with value YES and MallocStackLoggingNoCompact =1