# How to know whether the object is alive or not in Objective c With ARC

Tags: iphone, uitableview, search, automatic-ref-counting

Hi in my iPad application i am using the searchbar and tableview, after searching is done the results i am showing in a tableview. In order to update the table with new search results i am calling reloadData method. It is working fine but at few situations the app is crashing at [tableviewobject reloaddata] method and i am getting this error in console

error for object 0x95a0300: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.

By observing the above error what i understood is tableviewobject is removed from the memory. I am sending the message to the freed object. Inorder to overcome this issue what i did is i allocate the memory before  passing a message reloadData to tableviewobject as such

```
tableviewObject=[[UITableView alloc]init];
tableviewObject.delegate=self;
tableview.datasource=self;
[tableviewObject reloaddata];.
```

At the situation the results data is not updating in tableview. Now what i would like to know is how i can know whether the object is alive or freed from the memory. if it freed how to allocate the memory for a table view object for reload search results data. Please provide a solution for this if one have any idea . thanks in advance please help me.

**NOTE: IN MY PROJECT I AM USING ARC.**

Comment: read how many way this error occur http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424210/iphone-development-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated

Comment: It could also be any of the objects that are being accessed via your table view data source when reloadData is being called that have been released, and not necessarily your actual table view.  My guess is that one of the objects in your source array has been freed, and the key is to be sure to remove it from your data sources array when you free it so that this does't happen.  However, all of this is just a guess since you haven't included any code.  Show us what you are doing if you really want some help.  :)

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem on the simulator, run it under the Zombies instrument.  If you can only do it on the device, go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme… > Run > Diagnostics and check the “Enable Zombie Objects” checkbox.

Comment: How many tableviews are you using? Are you using UISearchBar alone or with UISearchDisplayController?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it catch your attention that in the third line the name of UITableView is misspelled?

```
tableviewObject=[[UITableView alloc]init];
tableviewObject.delegate=self;
tableview.datasource=self;
[tableviewObject reloaddata];
```

It should be tableviewObject.datasource=self;

Moreover, why create new object every time? You'll lose the old one by this! Just init it in the viewDidLoad method the first and only time

Answer (score 0):

As a more generic approach for a solution:

If you're using ARC you need to keep a hold to your objects or they will get freed for you.
In your above sample (let's assume you also meant to assign tableviewObject.datasource) you would need some property or class member to hold a reference to your tableviewObject.
E.g:

```
@interface MyViewController()  //anonymous private properties inside your .m
@property(nonatomic,strong) UITableView *tableviewObject;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize tableviewObject;
// rest of your implementation ...
@end
```

This way you would work with *self.tableviewObject* but that will stay available as long as the UIViewController with the property is alive.

*The generic thing to remember is simply that if you wan't to keep ARC from releasing something someone has to be using it (a reference or member property counts as **"using"**).*

In that respect the answer by thalador / user2413007 is also correct since the outlet will reference a tableview in a loaded XIB which basically has the same outcome.

Answer (score -1):

Do not create UITableView objects in code, you lose link between the view, if you create objects like this it will not help you can create property like this

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

This will solve your problem i think.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating objects in code, as long as you write it properly and make the right connections.

Comment: @Abizem in above code he is creating objects each when he want to perform reload .and also he is not adding tableview to the actual view .then how it has link ..

Comment: Which is why I said you need to write it correctly in the first place.